# history undefined in React V6

Tags: reactjs

```
const CartDropDown = ({ cartItems, history }) => (
  <div className="cart-dropdown">
    <div className="cart-items">
      {cartItems.length ? (
        cartItems.map((cartItem) => (
          <CartItem key={cartItem.id} item={cartItem} />
        ))
      ) : (
        <span className="empty-message"> Your Cart is empty</span>
      )}
    </div>
    <CustomButton onClick={() => history.push("/checkout")}>
      Go to checkout
    </CustomButton>
  </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  cartItems: selectCartItem
});

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(CartDropDown));
```

Comment: hi, can you improve formatting and add more of your code, please? it would be good if we can see the function declaration

Comment: React v6 means your Using react-router-dom V6???Improve question please.

Comment: let history = useHistory();
can you directly define and check.